# Does Google Geocoding API (V3) supports batch geocoding?

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

I've read all geocode service api [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) but haven't found anything about batch geocoding. May be I miss something and there is possibility to make a batch requests?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There is no way you can batch geocode a bunch of addresses but you can use the directions api to geocode up to 8 addresses. In the business class it allows up to 24 addresses. Read about it: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions. You can also try http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-tsp-solver/.

Comment: Sneaky way to get the same results

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. There are different limits for a free account vs an enterprise account. There is also a limit on how fast you can send requests per second.

Comment: Well but that does not answer the question? Sending multiple requests is not the same as sending one batch request....