# passing an array of addresses into the Geocode.geocoder() Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

**Description:**

I am using Google Maps v3. I have 25 dynamic addresses that I need to geocode at one time. We are currently working on a solution to store the lat/long in a database and remove the need to use Google's resources, but that is still a few months down the road and I need this geocoding functionality now.

**Question:**

Is there a way that I can send an entire array of full address into the `geocode.geocoder()` function? I have only seen examples where it was limited to one address at a time.

**Disclaimer:**

I have searched this site and could not find a solution. I have also google'd this exact question and haven't found anything.

Comment: No. It's one address at a time.

Comment: Search for [OVER_QUERY_LIMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-maps-api-3%5D+OVER_QUERY_LIMIT+Array)

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? Do you have a source for that Andy? I know what that is geocodezip... O_o

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) says `address — The **address** that you want to geocode` (my emphasis). The only way to do this is to loop over the array and submit each address individually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Google Geocoding API (V3) supports batch geocoding?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858376/does-google-geocoding-api-v3-supports-batch-geocoding)

Comment: Proving a negative is difficult. There may be a reason why there is no documentation on batch geocoding. This thread is a little old but he seems to know what he is talking about. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/how-to-geocode-300-000-addresses-on-the-fly

Comment: thank you Jeff for the resource!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **No**

Some great alternatives: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22108/how-to-geocode-300-000-addresses-on-the-fly

Not too sure if I should delete the question or not; kinda want to leave it up so duplicates aren't made. I would never have thought of the search query "batch processing"